# What are the downsides of creating SQL Server stored procedures in the following manner?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

We check in all our database objects into source control as rerunnable scripts (views, functions, triggers & stored procedures etc...)

When it comes time to deploy, we need to ensure that all the scripts are re-runnable & repeatable so that a stored procedure is be created/updated to the latest version.

Are there any downsides to creating the scripts in the following manner.

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT      * 
    FROM        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE       ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND         ROUTINE_NAME = 'MyStoredProcedure'
)
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure] AS SELECT 1')
    -- ALSO DO ANY INITIAL GRANT PRIVILEGE SCRIPTING HERE
END
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure] (
    @param1 INT,
    @param2 NVARCHAR(50) = 'Default String'
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- DO SOMETHING WITH @param1 AND @param2
    SELECT 1;
END
GO
```

Essentially the script checks to see if the object exists in the relevant system view, and if it doesn't exist, some dynamic sql creates it as a stub to get around `CREATE PROCEDURE/GO` statement issues not being allowed in conditional blocks. Then it applies the actual functionality of the script through an `ALTER`.

So the benefits are obvious to me, I'm just wondering are there any downsides to doing this... other than the slight overhead of writing slightly more verbose scripts.

Comment: You will probably get some close/subjective votes based on how you phrased this, and this might be better suited for DBA anyway, but I find this an interesting solution to a problem we had at a previous company.

Comment: Well I guess I'm looking for legitimate technical "downsides"... i.e. Are there any technical reasons to `DROP/CREATE` instead of `ALTERING`? Could `ALTERS` have any impact on Execution Plans etc...

Comment: It's a shame that the SQL Server is almost two decades old, and still they haven't gotten around to implementing a 'CREATE OR REPLACE' command.

Comment: ALTER doesn't affect the permissions on the procs.  If GRANTs change over time (and they did for us) then you'd need some way of accounting for that here (which might be easier with drop/recreate?)  I don't know of any reason from a performance/execution why they would act any differently.

Comment: @SWeko - Agree. [This is the 2nd most upvoted Connect Item request for SQL Server](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/127219/create-or-replace) posted in 2005. No idea why they couldn't get it in for one of the three releases since then (2008,2008 R2, or 2012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 year SQL Server developer/architect here, and I can't think of any downsides other than the (relatively slight) upfront cost of creating the  script that will do this.

If you are concerned that a plan compiled as trivial at the time of creation is not recompiled when the procedure is ALTERed, you could add an explicit call to SP_RECOMPILE for each, but I have never had this this problem with SQL Server (I have had it with DB2) and so I think that is excessive caution.

This is an interesting and I think useful approach.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't compile a plan at SP creation time. It gets parsed at create time but compiled on first execution and running `ALTER PROC` would invalidate any cached plans anyway.

Comment: You are correct, of course. :) I probably shouldn't have said 'at the time of creation'. I have run into this when application frameworks execute stored procedures when they compile and link, and only with DB2. As I said, I think this is an excessive degree of caution - it is really the only objection or caveat I could come up with.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dean & Martin. ~EoinC